# Few test cases returns a GET 500 Internal Server Error on Laravel

Tags: python, php, html, laravel, selenium-webdriver

So I have a laravel app testing project. I uses Selenium Python and Appium for the test script. It is already connected to the laravel, here is the UI:

[image]

As you can see, there are few test cases that are **Failed**, even though I checked on the Pytest report it returns a Passed. When I check the error logs on my website, there is a GET 500 Internal Server Error. For example the `Phone number starting 0` test case:

This is the console log:

[image]

The Pytest HTML report:

[image]

This is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class PhoneStartLoginScriptController extends Controller
{
    public function runPhoneStartLoginScript()
    {
        $command = 'pytest --html-report=pytest_phone_start_login.html ../automation/app.py -k "test_login_phone_starting_0"';
        exec($command, $returnCode);

        if ($returnCode === 0) {
            return response()->json('Script executed successfully', 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json('Script encountered an error', 500);
        }
    }
}
```

and the web.php:

```
Route::get('/run-phonestartloginscript', [PhoneStartLoginScriptController::class, 'runPhoneStartLoginScript'])->name('runPhoneStartLoginScript');
```

What I did:

1. Delete the .env file and create new, then `php artisan generate:key`, `php artisan cache:clear`, and `php artisan config:clear`
2. Restart the server
3. Remove .env from .gitignore

But nothing works

Comment: `When I check the error logs on my website, there is a GET 500 Internal Server Error` <<<=== the beauty of Laravel is that you can set the environment to `local` abd debug to `true` (.env file). That way you can get better error logging in your `storage/logs` log file. After you get that exception in your log file, show it in your original question. Also try to try/catch, so you can catch an exception

Comment: my .env already set environment and abd debug as you said, but when I check on the laravel.log it didn't display any error as the one on the console @UnderDog

Comment: Ok, adjust your php.ini to fully display startup errors, also error_reporting `E_ALL`. Definitely do try/catch, strange that the error didn't show in laravel.log. how about the web server's error log, can you check there?